# Existence of matrices $A,B$ with $AB=0\ne BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Do there exist matrices $A,B$ such that $AB=0$ and $BA\ne 0$?

Answer (score 4):

Sure.

$$A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\0 &0\end{array}\right],\quad B=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right].$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes there exist such matrices.

Find them.